Confusing Johansen cointegration test result using python
I am testing cointegration of three time series using Python.
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen

result = coint_johansen(data[['债券','黄金','股票']], det_order=1, k_ar_diff=0)

print("Eigenvalue Result")
print("NULL\t EIG\t 90%\t 95%\t 99%")
for i in range(len(result.lr1)):
    print(f"r<={i}\t {result.lr1[i]:.2f}\t {result.cvm[i][0]:.2f}\t {result.cvm[i][1]:.2f}\t {result.cvm[i][2]:.2f}")

print("Trace Statistic Result") 
print("NULL\t TRA\t 90%\t 95%\t 99%")
for i in range(len(result.lr2)):
    print(f"{i}\t {result.lr2[i]:.2f}\t {result.cvt[i][0]:.2f}\t {result.cvt[i][1]:.2f}\t {result.cvt[i][2]:.2f}")


This is the result I get:
Eigenvalue Result
NULL     EIG     90%     95%     99%
r<=0     32.88   21.87   24.25   29.26
r<=1     15.37   15.00   17.15   21.75
r<=2     4.51    2.71    3.84    6.63
Trace Statistic Result
NULL     TRA     90%     95%     99%
0    17.51   32.06   35.01   41.08
1    10.86   16.16   18.40   23.15
2    4.51    2.71    3.84    6.63

I have seen somebody answered similar question here. Johansen cointegration test: interpret the result In that example, for trace stats, traces are greater than critical values when r<=0,1,2 while less when r<=3,4,5, so it was concluded that cointegration rank is 3. But for my example, traces are less than critical values when r<=0,1 while greater when r<=2. In this case, what conclusion should I draw? Thanks in advance!
